# Calculate mean of multiple dataframes columns stored in List

Tags: r, function, loops

I'm doing some simulations and I have several dataframes with same columns stored in a list. For each dataframe, I want to create a new variable that has the mean of each row of a column from the 2 dataframes before (and the current one). I'm having problems formulating the loop. Here is a reproducible example:

```
#Create dataframe 
month <- 1:12
price <- 21:32
df <- data.frame(month, price)

#Separate each row and create a simulation of a new variable. Store new dataframes in a list
simulations <- 100
ints <- seq_len(12)
set.seed(96)
list <- lapply(setNames(ints, paste0("df", ints)), function(i) {
  cbind(
    df[rep(i, simulations),],
    q = as.numeric(runif(simulations, min = 5, max = 10)))
})

#for each df in list, calculate the mean of the last 3 values of q 
for (i in 3:length(list)) {
  list[[i]][["q_mean"]] <- mean(list[[(i-2):i]][["q"]]) #HERE IS THE PROBLEM
  list[[i]][["ben"]] <- list[[i]][["q_mean"]]*list[[i]][["price"]]
}
```

I'm getting "List error [[(i - 2): i]] [["q"]]: subscript out of bounds". Does anyone knows what could be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like @redarah has you on the right path, but one other comment -- I'd avoid naming a new object `list`, since there's already something in R with that name and it could cause unexpected behavior elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed two things that are causing you trouble here:

1 - When you subsetting your list like `list[[1:3]]` it gets read as `list[[c(1, 2, 3)]]`, and finds the 3rd entry (21) of the 2nd column (price) in the 1st element (df1) in the list. This is why doing something like list[1:2] returns a vector (it's pulling out an entire variable) and why list[1:4] returns an error (the list doesn't go 4 levels deep). (answer by @aaron-montgomery, from the comments)

2 - In your last line, you reference a column `mean` that you've never defined.

If you're trying to get one value that's the mean of all the previous elements, you can nest another loop:

```
#for each df in list, calculate the mean of the last 3 values of q 
for (i in 3:length(list)) {

  # add another loop to calculate the mean
  vals <- c()
  for (j in (i - 2):i) {
    vals <- c(vals, list[[j]]$q)
  }
  
  list[[i]][["q_mean"]] <- mean(vals)
  
}
```

If you want a different value for each row (where row1 is the mean of the previous 2 row1s, etc), you can just do:

```
for (i in 3:length(list)) {
  
  list[[i]][["q_mean"]] <- (list[[i - 1]]$q + list[[i - 2]]$q) /2
  
}
```

Comment: One correction: `list[1:3]` does something a bit more subtle than that -- since `1:3` is equivalent to the vector `c(1, 2, 3)`, this syntax will access the **third** entry of the `price` variable (i.e. the **second** column) in `df1`, the **first** data frame in the list. This is why doing something like `list[1:2]` returns a vector (it's pulling out an entire variable) and why `list[1:4]` returns an error (the list doesn't go 4 levels deep).

Comment: Thanks for the response! You are right, what I wanted in point 2 was to multiplicate q_mean with price column, not 'mean'. I already changed that in my post. Regarding your solution, I get the following error when I run it: ''Error in c(means, list[[j]]$q) : object 'means' not found''. Any idea of what could be wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: Oh sorry I had a typo! Fixed in the answer.

Comment: thank you @AaronMontgomery - updated my answer to reflect your comment!

Comment: Thanks! I just run your solution and it's great. Surely I was not clear enough in my post, but I want the q_mean column to show the mean of the last two dataframes for each row, so each value should be different. I believe your solution is calculating the mean of the entire column?

Comment: Oh - so you you want row 1 to be the average of the previous 2 row 1s, etc? Updated my answer above with the code for that^ !

Comment: Hi @redarah. I wanted to ask you if there is an efficient way of calculating the mean of, let's say, the last 6 months? If I use  (list[[i - 1]]$q + list[[i - 2]]$q+...+list[[i - 6]]$q) /6 it works but in some cases it would  take a lot of time of calculating the average manually. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This will do it if `q` is your only column:
`sub_list <- list[(i - 1):(i - 6)]`
`rowSums(bind_cols(sub_list)) / length(sub_list)`

If you have other columns, you'll need to select those

Comment: (something like this:
`purrr::map(sub_list, function(x) select(x, q)) %>% bind_cols() %>% rowSums()` and then dividing by `length(sub_list)`)